# Access 2000 Class Module Terminates Immediately After Initialization

Tags: ms-access

Any idea why this would be happening? I don't get any error inside the `Class_Initialize` sub, it just jumps straight to the `Class_Terminate` sub and the object I assign the class to ends up being `Nothing`.

Comment: Have you initialized a new instance of the class module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Access 2000.  See whether it has an error trapping option "Break in Class Module".  For Access 2003, that option can be found from the VB editor's main menu: choose Tools->Options, then select the "General" tab on the Options dialog.  The radio buttons for the Error Trapping choices are located on the middle right of the dialog.

It's not clear to me whether your class module is throwing an error silently.  That option should (I hope) help you expose the error ... if there is one.

If that effort is not useful, think I would next set a break point on the first executable line in Class_Initialize, and then step through the code one line at a time with the F8 key.  You can see which lines are executed, and at any time while you're in break mode you can inspect the values of variables by printing them to the Immediate Window ... with `Debug.Print YourVariable` or the shorter `? YourVariable`

A slicker way to monitor your variables is to open the Watches window (from the menu, View->Watch Window), then add variable to it (Debug->Add Watch).

Finally, if those efforts don't lead you to a solution, create a stripped down version of your class module with only the bare minimum code needed to reproduce the problem.  Add that code to your question, and also include enough of the calling code to show us how you're attempting to create and use the object instance.

Comment: I figured out what it was. I didn't have the Set command before the object I was assigning the new class to.

Comment: That's interesting.  I didn't expect `Class_Initialize` would even run without using the `Set` keyword when assigning it to an object variable.  However, stepping through code shows me it does, but then proceeds immediately to `Class_Terminate` Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Well, it's likely a matter of referring to the wrong class instance. Say your class is called `clMyClass` and your instance of it is `clsMyClass` defined with the variable `Dim clsMyClass as clMyClass`. You can refer directly to the class, `clMyClass` and it will initialize, but if you then try to refer to `clsMyClass`, it will not be initialized (since you didn't use the New keyword in defining the variable, nor issue a Set statement to initialize it).